# How to address postcss line return parsing error

Tags: reactjs, npm

In my project, when I try to install necessary node modules, I got some vulnerabilities.
Below is the error I encountered.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3HV7.png)
And I am already using the latest version of react-scripts(5.0.1) and @craco/craco(7.1.0).
How can I address all the vulnerabilities?

I tried `npm audit fix` to address above vulnerabilities and it only reports such details but no other fix.
I want to make my dependencies clear and remove all vulnerabilities.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please update your question with the code you have tried and the error message in text format.  We are un able to help questions that are just images as there is no code to copy and paste and work with.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest version of postcss package in your project folder. If this is not working. Then, Upgrade all packages in your project folder. Using the following command:

`npm i -g ncu`

After installing the ncu package globally. Then, use this command to change the version of the package.json.

`ncu -u`

After the update of the package.json. update the node_modules by using the following command:

`npm install`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).